# PDO prepared statement (update) is not working

Tags: php, pdo

I have this function inside a class. The insert is like exactly the same query (but with the INSERT obviously) and it works perfect.

I am trying now to update the database with the properties that the object has and it's not updating, it echoes "Rows not updated" I have tried everything and I have compared my code with examples that work and I dont know why it's not working! It's driving me nuts.

CODE:

```
public function update() {
    $query = "UPDATE ".$this->tablename." 
                SET 
                itemtype = :itemtype, 
                category = :category,
                title = :title, 
                content = :content,
                active = :active,
                keywords = :keywords,
                order = :order,
                featured = :featured
                WHERE id = ".$this->id;
    $this->conn->beginTransaction();
    $q = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $q->execute(array(":itemtype"=>$this->itemtype, "category"=>$this->category, "title"=>$this->title, 
                        ":content"=>$this->content, ":active"=>$this->active, ":keywords"=>$this->keywords, 
                        ":order"=>$this->order, ":featured"=>$this->featured));
    if($q->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo "Rows updated = ".$q->rowCount()."<br/>";
        $return = true;
    } else {
        echo "Rows not updated<br/>";
        $error = $this->conn->errorInfo();
        $this->SQLerror = $error[2];
        $return = false;
    }
    $this->conn->commit();
    return $return;
}
```

Just know that the errorInfo returns NULL, like if there was not any SQL Sintax Error!

Comment: If you can't find the problem (after having corrected the code, as user4035 said), be sure that your sql query is constructed correctly. Enable the DB's logging function to fetch the complete query executed on the server, and try to run this query directly from a DB client like phpmyadmin or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put colons here:

```
"category"=>$this->category, "title"=>
```

Should be:

```
":category"=>$this->category, ":title"=>
```

Make sure, the `$this->tablename` and `$this->id` don't lead to any syntax errors.

### Update

The word Order is reserved in SQL. Escape it with backticks:

```
`order` = :order,
```

Comment: All the class properties are set, I've var_dumped the object and they're perfectly set.

Well, you said I should put colons before each word, the code shows them already

Comment: @JuanBonnett Look carefully at your code, and you'll see, that colons are missing for these 2 properties, when you are executing the request.

Comment: @Miam84 yep, I'm sorry, may be I missed them because I modified te column names to make them more readable for the example. Anyway the original code has all the colons and it's not working.

I tried it with a normal Query in PHPMYADMIN and it says I have a sintax error near  'order = 1, featured = 1 WHERE administrableitems.id = 1' at line 8'

It's weird, because the query looks fine! I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

You are asking `if($q->$q->rowCount() > 0)` before `commit()` see [**Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)